Getting information about Dataflow worker crashes
What's the best way to confirm that Dataflow workers have crashed and how can we access logs that help explain the reason for the crash?
Context:
We have a streaming Dataflow pipeline that reads from Kafka developed with the Beam Java SDK using Dataflow Runner v2.
The current version of the pipeline scales down to a single worker, which is great from a cost perspective.
However it seems that the single worker crashes about every hour.
Unfortunately we currently only see very indirect signs when this happens.

Memory utilization, throughput go to zero
Backlog spikes and the recovers as the new worker(s) are launched
It takes about 5-10 minutes for the new worker(s) to start processing again
The autoscaler will temporarily launch up to 9 workers until the backlog is cleared again

The strongest signal that a worker crashed is log entries like this every hour or so:
Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 1 so that the pipeline can catch up with its backlog and keep up with its input rate.
Other than this, we haven't found anything in the logs indicating or relating to worker crashes.
There is some indication that the crashes only happens with runner v2, but we couldn't verify this for now.
Looking at the instance group the worker count sometimes can dip below 1, but likely due to sampling frequency this rarely shows up explicitly in the graphs:




Hi @Gergely, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Since you use Java for your streaming jobs, can you try to use the legacy runner if possible?
